# Making matching algorithm between two data frames more efficient

Tags: python, pandas

I have two data frames eg.

Shorter time frame ( 4 hourly )

```
Time                  Data_4h
1/1/01 00:00          1.1
1/1/01 06:00          1.2
1/1/01 12:00          1.3
1/1/01 18:00          1.1
2/1/01 00:00          1.1
2/1/01 06:00          1.2
2/1/01 12:00          1.3
2/1/01 18:00          1.1
3/1/01 00:00          1.1
3/1/01 06:00          1.2
3/1/01 12:00          1.3
3/1/01 18:00          1.1
```

Longer time frame ( 1 day )

```
Time                  Data_1d
1/1/01 00:00          1.1
2/1/01 00:00          1.6
3/1/01 00:00          1.0
```

I want to label the shorter time frame data with the data from the longer time frame data but n-1 days, leaving NaN where the n-1 day doesn't exist.

For example,

Final merged data combining 4h and 1d

```
Time                  Data_4h     Data_1d
1/1/01 00:00          1.1         NaN
1/1/01 06:00          1.2         NaN
1/1/01 12:00          1.3         NaN
1/1/01 18:00          1.1         NaN
2/1/01 00:00          1.1         1.1
2/1/01 06:00          1.2         1.1
2/1/01 12:00          1.3         1.1
2/1/01 18:00          1.1         1.1 
3/1/01 00:00          1.1         1.6
3/1/01 06:00          1.2         1.6
3/1/01 12:00          1.3         1.6
3/1/01 18:00          1.1         1.6
```

So for 1/1 - it tried to find 31/12 but couldn't find it so it was labelled as NaN. For 2/1, it searched for 1/1 and labelled those entires with 1.1 - the value for 1/1. For 3/1, it searched for 2/1 and labelled those entires with 1.6 - the value for 2/1.

It is important to note that the timeframe datas may have large gaps. So I can't access the rows in the larger time frame directly.

What is the best way to do this?

Currently I am iterating through all the rows of the smaller timeframe and then searching for the larger time frame date using a filter like:

```
large_tf_data[(large_tf_data.index <= target_timestamp)][0]
```

Where target_timestamp is calculated on each row in the smaller time frame data frame.

This is extremely slow! Any suggestions on how to speed it up?

Comment: Are those dates dayfirst or monthfirst?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, take care of dates

```
dayfirstme = lambda d: pd.to_datetime(d.Time, dayfirst=True)
df = df.assign(Time=dayfirstme)
df2 = df2.assign(Time=dayfirstme)
```

Then Convert `df2` to something useful

```
d2 = df2.assign(Time=lambda d: d.Time + pd.Timedelta(1, 'D')).set_index('Time').Data_1d
```

Apply magic

```
df.join(df.Time.dt.date.map(d2).rename(d2.name))

                  Time  Data_4h  Data_1d
0  2001-01-01 00:00:00      1.1      NaN
1  2001-01-01 06:00:00      1.2      NaN
2  2001-01-01 12:00:00      1.3      NaN
3  2001-01-01 18:00:00      1.1      NaN
4  2001-01-02 00:00:00      1.1      1.1
5  2001-01-02 06:00:00      1.2      1.1
6  2001-01-02 12:00:00      1.3      1.1
7  2001-01-02 18:00:00      1.1      1.1
8  2001-01-03 00:00:00      1.1      1.6
9  2001-01-03 06:00:00      1.2      1.6
10 2001-01-03 12:00:00      1.3      1.6
11 2001-01-03 18:00:00      1.1      1.6
```

---

I'm sure there are other ways but I didn't want to think about this anymore.

Comment: This is how I was going to do it myself, but I wanted to confirm if the dates were dayfirst. This confirms it though.